# Can you save $(this) as a variable?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to save $(this) as a variable inside of a jquery event so that you can compare it against other varaibles holding elements? If so, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: yes you can, `var saved = $(this);`

Comment: Sometimes useful to declare jquery vars with $ so you can keep things organized. `var $header = $('header'); var $last_clicked = $(this)`, etc

Answer (score 1):

I do this al the time! :)

```
var $el = $(this);
```

Note $ before el. This does nothing actually, it is for you to remember that this is jquery var.

Comment: now take the habit to prefix any jquery object with **$**  `$el` ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff yep, working on that :) but it doesn't come naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not.

```
$(element).click(function(){ //any event
    var th = $(this);
});
```